# How to customize the gallery shortcode in WordPress?

Tags: customization, gallery

I want to change WordPress's main gallery shortcode style to something like the picture below!

[image: sample slide show]

Any idea ?

Comment: Showing us the _picture_ is a little too little in this case. Which markup do you want to achieve? Which scripts to use? What code you have already?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the default gallery features already included in WordPress or install the Jetpack plugin which enables you to create tiled galleries. http://jetpack.me/support/tiled-galleries/

WordPress also includes a built in slide show feature and you can add thumbnail images underneath a full width image like what you linked to.